# How to add total for each groups in Multi Level Groups in Tabulator.js table

Tags: tabulator, calc, group

I have created a tabulator table with Multi Level Groups

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table",  {
groupClosedShowCalcs:true, //show column calculations when a group is closed
columnCalcs:"both", //true, both, table, group
groupBy:["CURR","ASSETS"],
...
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVyuF.png)

I want to display a Total for each level, unfortunately Total works only for last level...

In my example I have a first level with CURRENCIES and a second level with ASSETS

ASSETS subtotal works, not CURRENCY subtotal

Any ideas how can I fix that